Android Studio Button not aligned with the rectangular box
When I dragged a button into the design mode, the button is not centered within the rectangle box as shown in the picture. As a result, when I added constraints to the bottom, left, and right, the button disappears, only leaving the rectangle box visible. Is there anyway to resolve it?

The original code in the xml file is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rotationX="4"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="207dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="173dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


Remove layout_editor_absolute and constraint your button to parent with layout_constraint* attributes

Remove android:rotationX="4" from ConstraintLayout. For more info, please follow this link.

Tip: while creating UI using drag-and-drop may be easier, it's best to review the generated code as it might result in a less optimal UI.


thanks a lot. I unfortunately reinstalled and noticed that it doesn't have this rotationX = "4". Somehow I screwed it maybe earlier.

Because of ConstraintLayout, you must add an attribute to the Button. Replace your button with the code below so that it is centered.
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

